# How to access ubuntu files as root in php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a PHP script which runs in first server and it curls the PHP file which is on the second server.

```
$service_url = 'http://example.com/version_check.php?f_path='.$path;
```

On the second server, that PHP file (`version_check.php`) reads the files in `/var/www` directory and processes it.
Now I want to know how to access `/var/www` directory with root privileges.
I need root privileges because I am doing some `fwrite`s in that directory.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to be root to read files in `/var/www`. What user and group does the web server run as? What is the group, owner, and permissions of `/var/www` and the files in it?

Comment: @icktoofay I can access that /var/www directory with root permissions only.But i want to read that files with root privileges in php.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Requiring root privileges for non-admin tasks is usually the wrong solution, and a frequent source of security problems. Even running as a user with write privileges (like, say, `www-data`) from inside the web server is usually best avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using the default configuration on Ubuntu, you’ll have a user and group named `www-data` that your web server runs as. If you want to be able to write to a particular file, `chown` it to `www-data`:

```
$ chown www-data:www-data /var/www/my-file
```

Alternatively, keep the current ownership, change the group, and make it group-writable:

```
$ chgrp www-data /var/www/my-file
$ chmod g+w /var/www/my-file
```

As a last resort if you don’t want to change the ownership or group, make it world-writable:

```
$ chmod a+w /var/www/my-file
```

But this is a bad idea—*any* service on your system, good or bad, can modify the file, rather than just your web server. You should avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

**you don't.** just make the particular files or folders writable by www-data. running your PHP script as root would be a serious security problem. even more so, because I don't expect you to follow any common security guidelines (if you did, you wouldn't want to run your script as root).

Answer (score -1):

Kumaran,
The issue isn't PHP; the issue is the user accessing the files. Your PHP scripts are run by the *apache* user (www-data or apache, you'd need to check the username your apache's running under). The *apache* user, by default, can access certain files.
To be able to access files using root privileges, the *apache* user needs to acquire the rights to do so.

Allowing this to happen is a big security risk. You need to re-think the architecture altogether; why is PHP accessing root files in the first place? 
One option is to make the files in question writeable by the *apache* user

Answer (score -2):

The /root is only readable to root user. Hence you need to first move that Move file to /var/www and change it's permissions so www-data users can read it.

Comment: exactly where did the OP mention the `/root` folder? also, that's not true. read permission on directories is not inherited to their contents. so while `/root` is only readable (and executable) by `root:root`, a file `/root/test.txt` readable by some user can still be accessed by that path (you just can't see it in `ls`, because you can't `ls` the directory w/o read permission or `cd` into it w/o execute permission).